# Java ext4 slow file reading on big folder

Tags: java, performance, file, io, ext4

I have folder with two million of images 1-2KB.
I try to read

```
for (File f : tmpDir.listFiles()) {
   long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
   image = ImageIO.read(f);
   long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - t1;

}
```

first 20,000 files time = 0 or time = 1;

then time of reading increased up to 50-100 mls. (time = 50-1000)

How to improve performance?

Comment: on 64 linux, ext4 filesystem

Comment: Are you sure this is actually the IO, vs garbage collection for all those images you've created, for example? What happens if you just read each file, ignoring the actual data (thus avoiding repeated allocation)?

Comment: Did you try to increase max heap space to reduce garbage collection?

Comment: No, it is not a GC problem.

Comment: I agree with Jon Skeet, it looks like a Java GC issue caused by the many object allocations/deallocations. Here are a couple of ideas to prove this: (1) have a single file in the directory and read it over and over again -- I expect you will get the same results; (2) increase the java heap size -- I expect to see the latency increase much later; (3) monitor I/O traffic -- I expect you will find the block device underutilized (this means it is not an I/O issue); (4) monitor CPU usage -- I expect you will see a high userspace CPU utilization and very small kernel/system CPU utilization.